# Webpack excluding file from entry

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have a three entry points in webpack.config:

```
entry: {
   entry1: './app',
   entry2: './app/sub1',
   entry3: './app',
}
```

I need to exclude a single file(located in `./app/excluded/excluded_file.js`) from the `entry3`:

something like (that does not work in webpack) :

```
entry: {
   entry1: './app',
   entry2: './app/sub1',
   entry3: ['./app', '!./app/excluded/excluded_file.js'],
}
```

or using a Webpack plugin?

Comment: Hi @alireza-asadi. What do you mean with "extract a single file"? Just moving the file?

Comment: @toomuchdesign I mean exclude a single file...

Comment: @toomuchdesign I don't want to change any file in codebase, just using webpack config?

Answer (score 1):

If using a mock file is a viable option, you might override the undesired module path with the mocked one using [path-override-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-override-webpack-plugin) :

```
// webpack.config.js 
import PathOverridePlugin from 'path-override-webpack-plugin';

const webpackConfig = {
    plugins: [
        // Adjust the paths to the structure of your project
        new PathOverridePlugin(/^app\/excluded/, './mock-folder')
    ]
}
```